# Regex match any character 5 or more times

Tags: regex

I have this regex pattern:

```
^[.]{5,}$
```

Which I want to return true if the tested string has 5 or more characters.

I.E it'll only return false if the string contains 4 or less characters.

At the moment it seems to return true regardless of the number of characters and I can't see why.

Comment: This should return false in most cases, since `[.]` matches only the dot itself. You'd want to use `^.{5,}$`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want

```
^.{5,}$
```

But really - just use the built-in `string length` function of the language of your choice

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
 .{5,}
```

more chars to make up the minimum post...

Answer (score 3):

I think you dont need the ^ and $. Try just:

```
.{5,}
```

Comment: No that would mean exactly 5 characters